# Drupal search - alternative ways of doing it?

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-6

3rd Drupal question in a day.. guess what I'm doing!

OK, I've got the default Drupal search block, but I really need to find a way of restricting it to just searching one particular content type which is called "recipes" (guess what that one contains!)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can restrict the search and then go about controlling the output display?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Search config](http://drupalmodules.com/module/search-config) module. If this module does not your work you should also look at this page: http://www.drupalmodules.com. Just type in "search" and you can find a few search plugins with descriptions.

Comment: I've used search config with great success.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [Finder module](http://drupal.org/project/finder), which works well with CCK and filters and is straightforward to theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in trying [Faceted Search](http://drupal.org/project/faceted_search), which add a series of blocs to filter the results returned by the search module. There are many other modules which are related (see [Projects related with Faceted Search](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/facet%20search?filters=type%3Aproject_project)).